# Uniqueness validation on overlapping pairs of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, associations

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :petition
end
```

The `Request` class is designed to link an artist *or* user with a petition in a `has_many, through:` association. In the `Request` class, I'd like to validate that petition/artist pairs are unique, and that petition/user pairs are also unique, but neither user, artist, or petition individually have to be unique. Essentially, it has to fulfill this spec:

```
describe 'Request' do
  it 'is unique for a petition and artist pair' do
    r1 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, artist_id: 1)
    r2 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, artist_id: 2)
    r3 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, artist_id: 2)
    r4 = Request.new(petition_id: 2, artist_id: 2)
    expect(r1.save).to be_truthy
    expect(r2.save).to be_truthy
    expect(r3.save).to be_falsy
    expect(r4.save).to be_truthy
  end

  it 'is unique for a petition and user pair' do
    r1 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, user_id: 1)
    r2 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, user_id: 2)
    r3 = Request.new(petition_id: 1, user_id: 2)
    r4 = Request.new(petition_id: 2, user_id: 2)
    expect(r1.save).to be_truthy
    expect(r2.save).to be_truthy
    expect(r3.save).to be_falsy
    expect(r4.save).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

I tried using `validates_uniquness_of`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :artist_id, scope: :petition_id
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :petition_id
```

But specs don't work for r2 in both cases. Is there a built-in way to describe the validation I'm looking for, or will I have to write a custom validation?

Comment: I guess adding `unique indexes` to the `DB` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `allow_nil: true` to both validations.